# Data not being retrieved from SQL database when it is there

Tags: sql, objective-c, ios6

I have a difficult problem to explain but it has me baffled. I have the following in my iPad app:

1) Data is stored on my iPad using CoreData

2) Data is also stored in an SQL database

These data stores are synced from time to time so that any new data that has been collected on the ipad (in CoreData) is uploaded to the SQL database.

The syncing process works like this:

Step 1) CoreData data is loaded into an array

Step 2) SQL data is loaded into an array

Step 3) the two arrays are compared and if any records appear in the CoreData array then a php file is called to update the SQL database with the necessary data.

Step 4) SQL data is reloaded and displayed in a TableView.

This all works fine apart from step 4.

In step 4 I run the same procedure as I did in step 1 to retrieve the SQL data. The new data is visible in the SQL database however the routine only retrieves one record.

For example:
If I clear the SQL database of all records, run the syncing process (steps 1, 2 and 3) which adds 3 records, when step 4 retrieves the data (using the following code) it only returns 1 record even though the 3 records are visible in the SQL database. I don't understand why as the same code correctly retrieves the data in step 1, but not in step 4. Any ideas?

```
NSString *strURLClassRefreshed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://www.i-observe.co.uk/uploads/getiobserveinfo.php?schoolname=",obsSchoolName];
NSArray *observationsArrayClassRefreshed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLClassRefreshed]];
NSEnumerator *enumForObsClassRefreshed = [observationsArrayClassRefreshed objectEnumerator];
```

**UPDATE**
It appears that the php call in step 3 is not actually executed until the procedure is complete, ie after step 4. Therefore the data will not be there to be refreshed. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure your SQL query is returning more than one record in any step? The test you've outlined wouldn't spot it if it didn't. You may have a problem at the server end.

Comment: Yes - for example if I run this again with more new records in the SQL  and CoreData stores the NSArray *observationsArrayClass array in step 1 says it gets 3 records for example, then the new ones are added in step 3, but in step 4 NSArray *observationsArrayClassRefreshed shows only 1 again. Has me stumped!!